# Python "Switch-Case" alternative showing error

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, switch-statement

I was trying to implement a `C` like `switch-case` in `Python` using `dictionary` after following some codes. I've got the following code.

```
case = {'1': "case_1", '2': "case_2"}


def case_1():
    print "case 1"


def case_2():
    print "case 2"

x = raw_input("Enter 1 or 2 :")

if x == '1' or x == '2':
    print case[x]
    case_1()
    case[x]()
else:
    print "Please enter 1 or 2 only"
```

And I'm getting the output and error like bellow.

```
Enter 1 or 2 :1
case_1
case 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    case[x]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The actual problem** in your code is that, you are storing string values against keys. When you do, `case[x]`, it gives you only the string values and you are trying to invoke them as functions. That is why you are getting

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You can **fix** it by storing the function object itself in the dictionary, like this

```
def case_1():
    print "case 1"

def case_2():
    print "case 2"

case = {'1': case_1, '2': case_2}
```

Now, the functions are defined first (this is important, because you cannot use a function object before defining it) and then they are stored in the dictionary object. So, when the code

```
case[x]()
```

is executed, `case[x]` will actually return the function object and you can straightaway invoke it like you were trying to do.

**Note:** This is actually called "Command Pattern". You can read more about it, in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/182095).

---

> There is another way to make your program work, as it is. But I wouldn't recommend it.
>  
>  
>  You can actually invoke the function object corresponding to the strings, by getting the function object from the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary, like this `globals()[case[x]]()`.

Comment: Hidden in this (correct) answer is that you also will have to define the `case` dictionary *after* you define the functions.

Comment: @jedwards Oh yeah, I mentioned about that in my answer now.

Comment: 1st approach seems fine to me. I won't try the non-recommended one. :D

Comment: @Downvoter, if you are still around, please let me know what is wrong and how I can improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please change it ur code will done.

```
def case_1():
    print "case 1"


def case_2():
    print "case 2"

def run():
    x = int(raw_input("Enter 1 or 2 :"))
    print x
    if x == 1:
        case_1()
    elif x== 2:
        case_2()
    else:
        print "Please enter 1 or 2 only"

run()
```

Comment: It ain't "Switch-case alternative." You could do this in `C` too but `switch-case` has advantage over this.

Answer (score 0):

here is code of dictionary:

```
def case_1():
    print "case 1"


def case_2():
    print "case 2"

def run():
    dic={1:case_1,2:case_2}
    x = int(raw_input("Enter 1 or 2 :"))
    if x == 1 or x == 2:
        dic[x]()
    else:
        print "Please enter 1 or 2 only"

run()
```